# Doppler cooling before sideband cooling

Tags: quantum-optics, doppler-effect, cooling, ion-traps

I've seen that Doppler cooling is used to cool down the system before performing sideband cooling. I have 2 questions about it.

First, why do we need the system to be cooled before performing sideband cooling?

Second, I understood the Doppler cooling in ion traps (which is about using laser detuning on an atom) and Doppler cooling in optomechanical systems (which is also about laser detuning, but for the bad cavity regime). As I know, there is a conceptual difference between Doppler cooling and sideband cooling in ion traps physics, but for the optomechanical systems I can't see any difference, except the regime of the cavity (good cavities vs bad cavities). Am I right?